# What is the correct way to UPDATE a document in an embedded list?

Tags: orientdb

I am having some trouble finding a way to *update*, i.e. modify or delete a certain document in an embedded list. Here is my case:

```
CREATE CLASS Tag EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY Tag.label STRING
CREATE CLASS Profession
CREATE PROPERTY Profession.jobtitle STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Profession.tags LINKSET Tag
CREATE CLASS UserProfile EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY UserProfile.screenname STRING
CREATE PROPERTY UserProfile.profession EMBEDDEDLIST Profession
```

So, adding an entry to `UserProfile.profession` is no problem:

```
UPDATE UserProfile ADD profession =
   {"@type":"d","@class":"Profession","jobtitle":"Actress", "tags" : ["#22:5"]}
WHERE screenname = 'emma'
```

Given some entry 'emma' for UserProfile and a Tag with id #22:5.

However, when I try to update the Profession-document with jobtitle 'Actress', how exactly should I proceed? I tried the following approach, which worked with but one entry in the list only:

```
UPDATE UserProfile SET profession =
   {"@type":"d","@class":"Profession","jobtitle":"Actress", "tags" : ["#22:7", "#22:9"]} 
WHERE profession.jobtitle = 'Actress'
  AND screenname = 'emma'
```

This statement throws no exception and returns 0 as number of affected records.

In general: **How do I access a specific entry (using a key of the document itself) in an embedded list or set to update or remove it?**

Also: is there an easier way to update the tags linkset in the Profession-document in the embedded list? Or do I always have to get the whole document and write a modified version back?

Thanks!
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UPDATE UserProfile set profession = [{"@type":"d","@class":"Profession","jobtitle":"Actress", "tags" : ["#22:7", "#22:9"]}] 
WHERE profession.jobtitle contains "Actress" AND screenname = 'emma'
```

**UPDATE**

You could use this javascript function

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command("sql","select from userprofile");
var tag1=g.command("sql","select from #22:7");
var tag2=g.command("sql","select from #22:9");
for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    var screenname= b[i].getProperty("screenname");
    if(screenname=="emma"){
        var pro=b[i].getProperty("profession");
        for(j=0;j<pro.length;j++){
            if(pro[j].field("jobtitle")=="Actress"){
                pro[j].field("tags",[tag1[0],tag2[0]]);
            }    
        }
        b[i].save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the command rather substitutes the list with a new one, i.e, if there are two or more entries in the professions list after the UPDATE only the new entry remains.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE UserProfile SET profession.jobtitle = 'aaaa'
WHERE profession.jobtitle = 'Actress'
  AND screenname = 'emma'
```

Comment: This works ok as long as there is only one element in the profession list. - But thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: Hi, @IngoBrauckhoff. I know this was years ago, but did you find a solution in the end? I'm having the same problem.